# How to solve Error 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-503

I'm have problem with 503 Service Unavailable. My project is web application and it show data from 5 function by ajax and that function interval each 6 sec and sometime i get 503 error. i use firefox browser to run my application because i have to run autoplay audio too. Have anyone i have same project like me or have the same problem. Please share your solution to fix it. Thank you so much. I don't show my code because it's work fine and i think the problem is overloaded network. If you want to see the code please tell me.

Comment: Check server event viewer and logs to determine the cause of 503 error. May be due to some error the Application pool is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The following list could be the resolve of your problem.

1. .NET CLR Version & Managed Pipeline Mode
2. Enable 32-Bit Applications
3. Also you can Log errors in Application_Error method of global.config.
4. The Limitation of Your Web Host

complete illustration could be found in the following code.

https://www.bisend.com/blog/resolve-503-error

Comment: I'm follow with your step and waiting for error log in Application_Error to see what happen if i fix it already i will mark correct your ans.